# How do I temporarily disable the wincred provider for docker login?

Tags: windows, docker

I NEED the creds in plain text but docker login seems to store them in the windows cred provider by default now. I know it was changed to make it more secure, but more my purpose I need a plain text config file.

This is really frustrating because there seems to be no documentation explaining how to change the cred provider or change back to plain text.

The docker config file it generates doesnt' have any keys it just has this:

```
{
    "auths": {
        "gcr.io": {}
    },
    "HttpHeaders": {
        "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/17.09.0-ce (windows)"
    },
    "credsStore": "wincred"
}
```

How do I temporarily disable this so I can get a config I can use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is stupid but I "solved" this problem by renaming the provider itself so docker login couldn't find it:

```
"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker-credential-wincred.exe"
```

If you rename the exe and run login it fails, then if you run it again it succeeds and outputs the key in plain text in the config.json.

There has to be a simple way of selecting which provider you want to use or falling back to plain text without doing this, but the docs... suck.

I'll mark this as an answer if no one posts the correct way of doing this.

Comment: Ugly, but functional. As far as I can see, there is no specific value for `credsStore` to use the config.json file. Maybe setting `"credsStore" : "foobar"` could work as well without screwing with your docker install (as long as docker login doesn't "helpfully" override that back to `wincred`)

Comment: OMG. this actually work. remove "credsStore" and rename exe file. This is the only way.

Comment: The key point is that you have to both rename the exe file and remove credStore entry from config otherwise either the credStore entry is recreated or there is an error that the eincred executable is not found.

Answer (score 1):

If you have [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/wsl) enabled you can use `wsl docker --config . login` to store plain text `config.json` in current directory.